# Is the converse true for this theorem on double sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The theorem is:

> Let $(a_{m,n})_{m,n}$ be a double sequence that converges to a limit L. Assume that the sequence $(a_{m,n})_{n}$ converges. Then $\lim_{m\to\infty}(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{m,n})=L$.

Would the converse be true? Where if $\lim_{m\to\infty}(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{m,n})=L$, then the sequence $(a_{m,n})_{n}$ converges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, consider $a_{m,n}=\dfrac{m}{m+n}$, then $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{m,n})=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}(0)=0$.

Assume that $a_{m,n}\rightarrow L$ for some $L$, then $a_{m,m}\rightarrow L$ and $a_{m,2m}\rightarrow L$. But $a_{m,m}=\dfrac{1}{2}\rightarrow\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $a_{m,2m}=\dfrac{1}{3}\rightarrow\dfrac{1}{3}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Hello, is $a_{m,n}$ bounded?

Comment: Yes, it is bounded by $1$.